# Path related issue in Java EE web app

Tags: css, jsp, jakarta-ee, hyperlink

I have small Java EE web app developed in eclipse. I am using tomcat 6.0. In my application webcontent folder i have jsp folder and I have put all jsp files there.And I have css and JS folder which contains CSS and JS files.I have MVC design with single controller.From login page request go to controller and from there I am dispatching it to welcome.jsp.
 I have welcome.jsp where i am linking css with this code link 
href="css/stylesheet.css" 
its working fine.
 In that page I am using link a href="jsp/addEditUser.jsp" to go to addEdit user page. 
On addEdit.jsp page also i m using same 
 href="css/stylesheet.css"" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> but on that page it's not getting css. It gets css when i use  href="../css/stylesheet.css" 
why is it so..any solution..?

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute URLs like `/css/stylesheet.css` (with leading slash) resolved from root of host.

Answer (score 1):

there is no solution. your directory structure is like this :

```
 - css
 -- stylesheet.css
 - jsp
 -- addEditUser.jsp
```

the relative path from the jsp to the css is (parent directory)/css/stylesheet.css
 the ".." stands for parent directory.

Comment: I have tried <%=application.getContextPath()%>/css/stylesheet.css"